# How to restrain a creature in 5e following a successful Grapple

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions

I am interested in the *restrained* condition.  It's effects are [laid out pretty clearly](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Conditions#content) but I can't figure out how to apply it, after having grappled a creature.  What sorts of mechanical options are available for PCs to apply *restrained* to their enemies?

**Clarification**

I am not interested in grappling.  That only applies the *grappled* condition, and that doesn't seem like a huge amount of benefit.  If there's a way to turn *grappled* into *restrained*, though, that would be great.

Comment: Are you asking for a list of everything in 5th edition that imposes the "Restrained" condition?

Comment: Have you read the Player's Handbook or read the [Basic Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> If there's a way to turn grappled into restrained, though, that would be great.

## Check out the Grappler feat

The Grappler feat gives you access to the pin action:

> You can use your action to try to pin a creature grappled by you. To do so, make another grapple check. If you succeed, you and the creature are both restrained until the grapple ends.

This lets you turn a grapple into the restrained condition (albeit in exchange for leaving you restrained as well).

### Other options for restraining.

There are a many other effects that restrain targets. Here is a listing of some of the sources for them:

1. **Spells.** A number of spells impose the restrained condition.
2. **Net.** The net is a special ranged weapon that can be a used to restrain a creature.
3. **Magic Items.** There are some magic items that allow you to restrain a creature.

Answer (score 2):

## Use your imagination

Much of role playing is about coming up with a description of how the story progresses and things come to be.  The conditions, rules, effects, etc.. are the collective agreement that eases collaborative story telling.

For example, manacles and chains have historically been used to restrain prisoners.

### Rules Guidance

Check out some of the spells, traps, monsters, or feats that cause the effect.  Additionally, Xanthar's Guide to Everything has a section on Tying Knots.

Comment: I can't upvote until later, as I have used up all of my votes for the day.  Will check back.

Comment: I believe that the OP was interested in finding out what some of those feats and spells *were*.  I admit that I don't personally know of any, and I'm not sure how I'd go about finding them, short of reading the spell lists one by one.

Comment: @BenBarden added a simple example to illustrate an admittedly unimaginative example.